# Convert Nodejs server into node module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to convert a nodejs API server into a node module, which can be used for other projects without making much code changes?

**Details:** There are several API's(get, post, put) in the node js server. So if I use this server as a node module inside another node server, I must be able to access the API's in the node modules directly from the client. Is this possible? If yes, how?

I am required to do a POC on this for a client requirement and so far did not find it possible. Can you please help? I am relatively new to node js development

Comment: well you can do this but it will take some time. you need the main nodejs to listen to the http and send your app object to you module(useing express) if you can share your code i can help you arrange it

Comment: Thank you so much. Your idea worked. Now I am able to use the server as a node module. Please post a example code for your idea. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main script

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
/*
use some middlewares 
*/
require('my-module')(app)


const server = http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT);


module.exports = app;
```

module

```js
module.exports = (app) =>{
  app.get('/',(req,res) =>{
    res.send('hi im a diffrent module;')
  }
}
```